# Adobe DTM Page Load rule with Custom Rule Condition

Tags: adobe

I'm trying to fire a rule when the custom rule condition is met.
The Problem: I have a page load rule that I would like to fire whenever it finds s.events = event4 (which is basically an event that comes back once the user is successfully registered). 
I have basic code knowledge, so I tried

```
if (s.events == "event4")
return true;
```

I also tried

```
    if (typeof(events) == "event4")
    return true;
```

and

```
    var s = AdobeAnalytics.s.events;
 if (s.events == "event4")
    return true;
```

and the response most of the time comes back as:
Cannot read property 'events' of undefined
Condition function (e,t){var n=AdobeAnalytics.s.events;return"event4"==n.events?!0:void 0} for rule "Registration Success" not met

Can you please help me to write down the code for this page load rule condition

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to fire a page load rule based on a variable being set rather than triggering the page load rule on the same event that sets the variable?

Comment: Here is the code that triggers event4 (which I didnt write)

       `if( typeof(formSuccess) == "string" ){ 
            if( formSuccess !== ""){
                s.events = "event4"; //success event for registration
                 
            }
        }`

What should I put there to fire the page load rule based on this code?

Comment: Without seeing the page, It sounds like you should be able to create an Event-based rule that uses the form submit condition to set s.events = event 4. You can also choose in the Analytics section if you want a s.t or s.tl call.

There are some good videos around how to use the different rules in DTM on this YouTube Channel - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOdw8u2F8CIj0XorU_WNQDqjOoNVho7nv